# How do you display a custom field on a new page?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Please bare with me because I am new to this this.

So I created a new template for a page.

```
<?php
    /**
     * Template Name: Sponsors For Homepage
     */
    ?>

    <html>
    <body>
    <?php get_header('sponsor'); ?>

    <div class='divone'>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

    <div class='divtwo'>
    <?php sponser_advertisement(); ?>
    </div>

    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And I added a new custom field for the template. Using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin 4.4.8[image]

I made sure that the field would show on the correct template:
[image]

The fields showed up on my template page

But for some reason the field does not show up when I preview my page on the browser.

Thanks in advance.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you on wordpress.com or wordpress.org?

Comment: I'd put in an ACF ticket. I've run into the same issue, ACF fields or other postmeta not showing in a preview, not sure there is a fix. You can publish it as "private" so it's not publicly viewable, but publishing will let you see the ACF field or postmeta.

Comment: Is `sponser_advertisement()` a function you've created? I suggest reading [ACF documentation on how to output the contents of your fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/).

Comment: @Kenneth I'm running Wordpress locally.

Comment: @ Milo 29 sponser_advertisement is not a function but a field that I created using the Advance Custom Fields plugin

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (get_field ('sponser_advertisement')) {
 echo 'this is my field: '. get_field ('sponser_advertisement');
} 
?>
```

(however you spelled sponsor wrong...)  :)